# flask endpoint for ajax call

Tags: flask, jinja2

I'm making an ajax call to my server while pressing submit button.
Button is present in page http://127.0.0.1:5000/post/15.

Jquery function invoked and the endpoint definition for submit_comment in python respectively:

```
function submit_comment(post_id) {
    var uname = $('input[name="uname"]').val();
    var comment = $('textarea[name="comment"]').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/submit_comment",
        data: {name: uname, comment: comment, post_id: post_id},
        method: "POST",
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log('reaches here');            
            addElement(response);
            console.log('Is it me');
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log('reached Error');
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

py

```
@main.route('/submit_comment', methods = ['POST', 'PUT'])
def submit_comment():
    entry = request.get_json(force=True)
    print 'comment:', entry
    ....
```

Main is the blueprint. But I'm getting following 404 error.

127.0.0.1 - - [24/Aug/2017 10:30:55] "POST /post/submit_comment HTTP/1.1" 404 -

I am wondering from where this post got appended into the endpoint.
Can someone help me to understand the error and resolve it?

Thanks,
Deepak

Comment: Why do you have a PUT request ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a lot, but I know that the Flask docs on ajax say to query for the script root like this:

```
$SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson }};
```

and then use that as part of the request URL.

An example from an ajax call I've used (`$.getJSON` being a jquery function for `$.ajax`)

```
$.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '{{ url_for("help_email") }}',
```